# Which one is not always true: $\det(A^tB)=0$ or $\det(AB^t) = 0$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

I had this on an exam recently and I am not exactly sure about it.

> Let $A,\ B$ be matrices with $A,\ B \in M_{m \times n}(K)$ with $m < n$ and $K$ a field. Which of the following statements is not always true? $$\det(A^tB)=0$$ $$\det(AB^t) = 0$$

Which is the one and why?

Comment: Think about what the answer would be if $m = 1 < n$. Then generalize.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:** $A$ and $B$ have rank at most $m$.  So, both $A^TB$ and $AB^T$ have rank at most $m$.  How does that relate to the determinant?

Comment: That was exactly what I thought then and used in my proof! Thanks!